# Intersection Number of $B = Y^2 - X^3 + X$ and $F = (X^2 + Y^2)^3 - 4X^2Y^2$ using the fact $I(P,F \cap B) = ord_P^B(F) $.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Firstly, I apologise that this question is specific to two polynomials. I understand that this post will not help a lot of people, and for that I am sorry. I will make it up to you all by anwsering lots more questions in the future! However, as my lecturers enjoy time off on the weekend, I am unable to ask this to anyone else who would know what the heck I'm talking about. Sorry if my notation is not widely used, I can elaborate more if required. Please excuse my poor Latex too.

Let:

$B = Y^2 - X^3 + X$, and

$F = (X^2 + Y^2)^3 - 4X^2Y^2$.

I wish to find the intersection number of $B$ and $F$ at $P = (0,0)$

i.e $I(P,F \cap B). $

**However, I want to use the following proposition to do this:**

If $P$ is simple on $B$ then $I(P,F \cap B) = ord_P^B(F) $.

I will omit proving that $P$ is simple on $B$ as I hope it is clear to see it is.

I know that $I(P,F \cap B) > M_p(F) * M_p(B) = 1 * 4 $, where $M_P(G)$ is the multiplicity of $P$ on $G$.

Now, consider the Image of $X$ and $Y$:

$K[X,Y] \longrightarrow \frac{K[X,Y]}{Y^2 - X^3 + X} \longrightarrow O_P(Y^2 - X^3 + X)$

$X \longrightarrow x$

$Y \longrightarrow y$

*Where lower case denotes the image.*

Then $ord_P^{Y^2 - X^3 + X}((X^2 + Y^2)^3 - 4X^2Y^2)$

Can be found by substituting $y^2 = x^3 - x$ into $(x^2 + y^2)^3 - 4x^2y^2$

Which gives:

$ord_P^{Y^2 - X^3 + X}(x^9+3x^8 -5x^6 -4x^5 +3x^4 +3x^3)=3$

i.e $I(P,F \cap B) = 3$, a contradiction to  $I(P,F \cap B) > 4$ as above.

The correct answer I know is 6, so where have I gone wrong?

Comment: +1 Don't worry: your question is excellent **precisely** because it is so specific so that throwing pretentious mumbo-jumbo at it won't be of much help in solving it. What book or document are you using?  By the way $ord$ is given by lowest term so that in your attempt you should be lured into saying that the required intersection number is $3$, which however is false too!

Comment: Thanks Georges. Correction, noted! I am using "Algebraic Curves: An Introduction to Algebraic Geometry" by William Fulton, of which this question has been taken (see 3.17).The book has been made freely available to all, at http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to the solution is that the curve $C=V(B)$ is indeed smooth at $P$ **and** that a uniformizing parameter there is $y$, since $\frac {\partial B}{\partial x}(P)\neq0$ .
On the other hand the function $x$ satisfies $ord_P(x)=2$ since $x=-y^2+x^3$ and moreover $x^2=y^4+\cdots$, where $\cdots$ are higher order terms.
Then the order of $(x^2 + y^2)^3 - 4x^2y^2=(y^4+\cdots+y^2)^3 -4(y^4+\cdots)y^2=-3y^6+\cdots$ is $6$, just as  you  seemed to know.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!I see my mistake in not associating the uniformizing parameter y from the proof that P is simple on B (i.e the partial derivative w.r.t x at P). I had the right idea, but the wrong variable! Thanks again Georges.

Comment: You are welcome, dear jakey. And don't worry: your mistake is quite natural.  It is indeed a bit confusing  that once you know that the partial derivative with respect to $x$ is not zero, you deduce that $y$, **the other variable !**, is the uniformizing parameter ...